# main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): When try to place order

Tags: magento2

I've the latest magento's version with PHP 8.1
Upgrade from older version.
When place order in default language all is ok.
When place order in other language (is a multilanguage store) an error occurred:
main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3
I've stripe module installed.

In older version of magento I've also a module for "pay on delivery" but I'm sure I've removed it.
My idea is there is some trace in DB or code of the older module "pay on delivery"

Can someone help me to find the problem? to debug?

Thanks

Comment: Post the Complete error, the issue is that variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated function str_replace() in your Magento 2 code. The str_replace() function has been flagged as deprecated in PHP 8.1 version, which means that it is no longer recommended for use and may be removed in future versions of the language.

To resolve this you can use 'strtr()' function, which performs the same task of replacing characters or substrings in a string.

For example Replace the string "Hello world" with "Hi earth":

$arr = array("Hello" => "Hi", "world" => "earth");

echo strtr("Hello world",$arr);

You need to search for and replace all instances of str_replace() in your code to resolve the issue.

Comment: str_replace is not deprecated in PHP 8.1. But it will throw a warning because passing null values to str_replace has been deprecated. So when you call the function you can replace a call like str_replace($var1, $var2, $var3) with str_replace($var1 ?? '', $var2 ?? '', $var3 ?? ''). Or before calling str_replace make sure all the arguments you are passing to it are either string or array as the function expects. Nulls are no longer allowed.

Answer (score -1):

The file in which you are getting the error for str_replace, find the line no. and check the code if you are not sure then.

Example: $onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");

if the code is something like this replace with

$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels ?? '', "", "Hello World of PHP");

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I've not undestand how to find the file that generate the error!